# Error-cannot find module 'config-chain'

Tags: node.js

After running the command 
    mean init myapp
I  ran the command
    mean package mypack

I get the error - cannot find module 'config-chain'

Comment: I tried repeating the installation using 'npm install -g mean-cli' ,'mean init myapp 'and then 'cd myapp && npm install'

Answer (score 0):

After the execution of the command 'mean init appname'
Try executing the following:

1.To see whether the protocol has been https or http, run the command

'npm config ls -l'

2.If you find registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/" then run...

npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"

3.finally

npm config set strict-ssl false

again start with npm install.
For me the problem was solved.